# como puedo mostrar solo un nombre del select con el evento onchange y imprimirlo en un td aqui solo lo muestro por consola

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

como puedo mostrar solo un nombre del select  con el evento onchange utilizado en un select y imprimirlo en un td aqui solo lo muestro por consola, intente con este script :

```
 <select name="nav" id="select">
        <?php while ($tall = $tallas->fetch_object()): ?>
            <option value="<?= $tall->id  ? 'selected' : ''; ?>">
                <?= $tall->nombre ?>
            </option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#select").on("change",function(){
            var valorSelect=$(this).text()
             console.log(valorSelect)
        })
        
        })
    </script>
```

Me imprime todos los valores contenidos en el **select** y no, el seleccionado por el **select** . El valor seleccionado lo quiero imprimir en un  luego de haberlo traido en el **ahref**, no se mucho javaScript , solo html y php me diefiendo.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, para que solo te coja el value del select en vez de todo, usa `.val()` en vez de `text()`

Y luego si el `<td>` tiene un id, tienes que utilizar `.html()` para modificar el html de ese `<td>`

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo

```js
    $("#select").on("change", function () {
        $('#td').html($("#select").val())
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
    <option value="a">
        a
    </option>
    <option value="b">
        b
    </option>
    <option value="c">
        c
    </option>
    <option value="d">
        d
    </option>
</select>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Valor Seleccionado</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="td"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias me funciona, pero hay una cuestión, el <td> tengo que imprimirlo en otra vista diferente en donde esta el select como llevo ese <td> a la otra pagina. Gracias.